# Как подставить атрибут rel через JS

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Есть код:

```
var i=document.createElement('img');
ia.appendChild(i);
i.src=imgdir+'/'+id;
i.rel='lightbox[roadtrip]';
```

Через i.rel не подставляются значения лайтбокса. Пытался сделать i.alt в таком случае срабатывает, но значения присваиваются к атрибуту alt=""

Comment: Мой косяк :D не досмотрел ) надо за кофе на обеде идти срочно) Конвертируй в ответ :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` не имеет арттрибута rel только для `a`